# What will I get if no HOST is specified (HTTP 1.0) when sending a request to the server?

Tags: apache, http, server, http-headers, host

What will I get if no HOST is specified (HTTP 1.0) while sending a request to the server?
I know the answer for HTTP1.1, but what is in the case with HTTP1.0?

Answer (score 0):

As `Host` is a header [introduced in HTTP/1.1](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2068#section-14.23), omitting it should have no effect in HTTP/1.0.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! But still, I don't understand what will happen: some default server will be used or will I get the bad request error (400), or what? As I remember, there must be different situations with different consequences, but I can't remember which exactly.

Comment: In HTTP/1.1, an IP address is assumed to belong to one domain at most (one domain can resolve to multiple addresses, though). There really is no host besides the "default." The only way around that is to map by different ports. Anyhow, setting or omitting that header should have no influence.

Comment: And whatäs about HTTP/1.0?